# Adding comments to waveform

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

Can anyone give me a hint on how to create comments in a waveform, using wavesurfer.js? Just like SoundCloud does it.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get the same time as 00:00 you can do the following for example:

```
function timeformat(timeget) {
    if (!timeget) {return "00:00";}

    var min = Math.floor(timeget / 60);
    var sec = Math.ceil(timeget) % 60;

    return (min < 10 ? '0' : '') + min + ":" + (sec < 10 ? '0' : '') + sec;
};
timeformat(wavesurfer.getCurrentTime());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Vini! Do you have an idea how I can display a tiny thumbnail at the right timecode in the waveform or below?

Comment: Did you get this working?  Please share if so!!!  Thanks a lot!!